# Prove that $f$ in monotonic

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity

In my assignment I have to prove the following:

> Let $f$ a continuous function in $\Bbb R$. 
>   Prove the following:
>
> if $|f|$ is monotonic increasing, in R then $f$ is monotonic in R.
>
> Hint: Prove that $f(x)\ne 0$ for every $x \in \Bbb R$

My proof is rather long and I didn't use the fact the $f$ is continuous, which is kind of worrying. 
Is there a way proving that with using the continuity?

Please let me know if I have a mistake somewhere, as I want to know if I'm correct.

> **Proof**

Assume in contradiction that there is some $x=0$ such that $f(x)=0$

$$==>f(x)=0\to|f(x)=0|$$
Since $|f|$ in increasing, there is some $f(x_1)$ such that $$|f(x_1)|<|f(x)| =>|f(x_1)|< 0$$ That means the I found two values which in them |f| is decreasing which is a contradiction. Therefore, $$f(x)\ne0$$ for all $x$.

I claim that $x>0$ for all x.

**Proof of that statement:**

Assume in contradiction that there is $x<0$ such that $f(x)=y$

- if $f(x)<0$ then there is some $t$ such that $f(t)=0$ according to the intermidate value theorem. That is a contradiction to the fact that $f(x)\ne0$
- if $f(x)>0$ then $|f(x)|=f(x)$ so according to intermidate value theorem there is some $t$ such that $f(t)=0$, in contradiction to my previous proof.That is also a contradiction to the fact the $|f(x)|$ is increasing.

Therefore, x>0 and |f| is increasing.

- If $f(x)>0$ then $f$ is increasing since $|f|$ is increasing.
- if $f(x)<0$ then $f$ is decreasing since $|f|$ in increasing. I assume is contradiction the opposite and prove accordingly.

I'm sorry it's that long. Is my solution true?

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's too complicated and some aguments seem to be not justifief: e.g. Why do ypu try to prove $x> 0$  for all $x$? $x$ is the variable, it can take any value. As you noticed, we can't have $f(x=0, because this is the same as $\lvertf(x)\rvert=0$, which would imply that if $x'

From there, as $f$ is continuous, $f(x)$ has always the same sign (else it would have a root by the IVT).

If $f(x)>0$, then $f=\lvert f\vert$, and it is increasing. If $f(x)<0$, then $f=-\lvert f\vert$, and it is decreasing.